# Prolog: read predicate omits some parentheses in the user input

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog. I am trying to solve a number link puzzle with varying board size and start end positions of the points to connect. Since the board configuration detail vary, I am getting all those details from the user. In order to obtain the user input I am using read/1 predicate in prolog. But when I try to write the user input again I observe some parenthesis missing which are kind of important for me to further process. Following is a the sample code I was working with along with the input and output.

```
number_link_puzzle(Input):-
read(Input),
write(Input).
```

Here the input value is: 7, 5, (1: (5,2), (4,3)), (2: (3,2), (4,3)).
Notice the parenthesis surrounding (4,3) coordinates.
But the output that I get when I write the user input back is X = (7,5,(1:(5,2),4,3),2:(3,2),4,3).

Where 4,3 are not surrounded with parenthesis. Since the parenthesis in the input is important for my further processing in my program, I would like to know why this parenthesis are being omitted, or is there any other alternative I could use to accomplish this?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: `read/1` reads a Prolog term. In that context, the parentheses are all meaningful to Prolog and so Prolog is free to manipulate them as it desires to maintain how Prolog parses such terms. In this case, the comma is right-associative in Prolog, so to Prolog, the parentheses in `(4,3)` appear redundant, so it doesn't include them when writing the term out. If you need to interpret each token in your own way, you'll need to read the input as a string and parse it. Or, just write your predicate knowing that Prolog interprets the comma this way.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion 1: force the user to write a valid Prolog term and run the program as a query from the top level. It could look like this:

```
?- number_link_puzzle(puzzle(7, 5, x(1, 5-2, 4-3), x(2, 3-2, 4-3))).
```

I have no idea what puzzle this is (because you didn't say) so I don't know if this is the best way to write it. But at least now you can use pattern matching in the head to "extract" (or rather just access) all values. The head of your predicate would look like this:

```
number_link_puzzle(puzzle(A, B, x(C, D-E, F-G), x(H, I-J, K-L)))
```

Just to put some working code here, let's make it print out all the variables in there:

```
number_link_puzzle(puzzle(A, B, x(C, D-E, F-G), x(H, I-J, K-L))) :-
    format("~w", [[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L]]).
```

And with the query above you'll get:

```
?- number_link_puzzle(puzzle(7, 5, x(1, 5-2, 4-3), x(2, 3-2, 4-3))).
[7,5,1,5,2,4,3,2,3,2,4,3]
true.
```

This is an easy way of dealing with such problems: just avoid the problem. Suggestions 2 and 3 involve unnecessary work and I won't write fully working code.

Suggestion 2: You can use `read/1`, but change your representation so that it is a valid Prolog term. Unnecessary because it is just a roundabout way to implement suggestion 1.

Suggestion 3: Use something like `read_line_to_codes` to read all input to a code list (or char list), then use a DCG to parse it. This means you can come up with whatever representation you want, but you must then parse it to extract the data from it.

Something along the lines of:

```
puzzle(p(A, B, C, D)) -->
    number(A), ", ",
    number(B), ", ",
    x(C), ", ",
    x(D).

x(x(A, B-C, D-E)) -->
    "(", number(A), ": ",
    pair(B, C), ", ",
    pair(D, E), ")".

pair(A, B) --> "(", number(A), ",", number(B), ")".
```

This will actually work if you had SWI-Prolog and added

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).
```

on top of it.

```
?- phrase(puzzle(P), `7, 5, (1: (5,2), (4,3)), (2: (3,2), (4,3))`).
P = p(7, 5, x(1, 5-2, 4-3), x(2, 3-2, 4-3)).
```